# Trying To Call a Dynamic Email Address

Tags: php

I have added a contact form to a script on my site. Right now I am sending the request form to the Admin's email with:

```
$to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
```

Being my theme allows for several agents, in the contact form I can call that agents email to display above the form with:

```
<p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:11px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p
```

[image]

Instead of email always going to Admin's email I would like it to go to the person's dynamically generated email that is highlighted in the picture. I just can not figure out how to call that dynamic email correctly with the $to = get_option('**');.

Here is the page: http://teamambrose.realtor/property/mls-t3110937-9313-mandrake-ct-tampa-fl-33647/

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for replying. The page is: http://teamambrose.realtor/property/mls-t3110937-9313-mandrake-ct-tampa-fl-33647/ going to add to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this page belongs to an agent:

```
<p>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <span style="font-size:11px"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ); ?></span>
</p>
```

Assuming this page *does not* belong to the agent, but the email is stored in the page's custom field named, for example, `agent_email`:

```
<p>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <span style="font-size:11px"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'agent_email', true ); ?></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Max, that line of script is working as I had hoped and calling the agents email and displaying it. What I can not figure out is the contact form. Presently I am sending the request to the Admin's email with: $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );. What I can not figure out is how to send the request to the email address that is populated there with: ><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:11px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p>. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I was hoping it was as simple as: $to = get_option . sh_set($meta1, 'email'); but that doesn't work. Being, I am only a hack I think I am not calling correctly due to my short comings.

Comment: You have to change `$to = get_option( whatever );` to one of the functions above (which works for you). But I can't know where exactly because I know nothing about you theme, so you have to figure out it yourself or ask the theme developer.

Comment: This is what is throwing me Max: sh_set($meta1, 'email'). I dont know how to call that script correctly

Comment: I have tried this: $to = get_option(sh_set($meta1, 'email')); and get an error. Something is wrong in there that it does not find the email to send to.